# Release my framework with opensource license

Tags: c#, open-source, frameworks

I've made a framework in C# that allow to develop a complete application with only few line of code.
I think that it will be usefull for some other, and that i need a lot of time for refine it.

I've not experience with opensource project and i need to know what is the best way to make some profit from it.

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I think that i'll release only a piece of the fw with opensource license and the rest with a commercial license. This because I do not have fully understood the opensource mechanism, and i don't wont to give year of work for free.

this means that if it work fine, all fw will be opensource a day.

thanks to everyone

Comment: What is your top priority? Having an open source project? Or making money from your efforts on the framework?

Comment: "opensource" and "profit" don't really belong in the same sentence.

Comment: @Tim They don't inherently go hand-in-hand, but they are by no means antithetical. There are plenty of "open source companies" (in quotes for a reason, the way those companies make money is often through closed-source value add, etc) that do fine, with various business models.

Comment: A complete application with only a few lines of code?  Where have I heard this before?

Comment: You can open source your framework,and as it grows in popularity it might get adopted by one or two bigger companies who would be willing to pay for support either on a retainer basis or when they discovered a program.   However the hard part is evangelizing your framework to increase adoption.

Comment: @yodaj007 yes, I've heared this before like you. I use my fw in every desktop project in last years, and it work very well for me (according my customers too). Now I realize that it became complete, and i think that i can monetize years of improvements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to profit from a one-person open source project is to use it as a portfolio item to get a good job.  Making money from it any other way would probably take more effort than it's worth.  Your type of project, in particular, would be very difficult to differentiate from the abundance of App-Inventor-type frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the most profitable approach for Open Source companies to make money is to sell support licensing.

Given as your product is a framework, you might want to re-evaluate if you want to sell it, or if you want to release it as Open Source, as in your case I'm guessing your customers wouldn't generally be interested in support contracts.